# Different users across different feature files executed during a single runner execution - variable instantiation

Tags: karate

Recently, we built in support in our configs and feature files to authenticate with a user pulled from a json file.  This authentication works great if the same user info is applied to all the feature files, but when we run multiple feature files with different user, the authentication seems to stick to a single user rather than being associated (containerized) to the feature file itself, resulting in 1 set of feature files working as expected and the other failing.

To give you an example,

- we have 2 different users (1 active user and 1 inactive user)
- we have authentication for each feature file (active user and inactive user) which is called in a shared .js file (authentication)
- as we execute the feature files, we notice that the active user scenarios all pass, but the inactive user scenarios fail

- upon looking at the authentication used for each scenario, we notice that it is the same between both feature files.

Unsure if this is a first or last run of authentication wins, but the variable (authToken) which we use, is not differentiated between feature files.

Is this normal meaning we can only run a set of feature files specific to a single user at a time, and different users would require different runners or authentication specific variables rather than using a shared .js function?

```
active feature -> calls auth.js -> instantiates at a gloabal level - authToken
inactive feature -> calls auth.js -> instantiates at a gloabal level - authToken

which instantiation of authToken wins - first or last...
```

Or is this a bug in which the background for a feature file should be specific to that file even if the source function(s) is a shared resource?

```
active feature -> calls auth.js -> instantiates at a feature (class or function) level - active.authToken
inactive feature -> calls auth.js -> instantiates at a feature (class or function) level - inactive.authToken
```

Comment: Should Background possibly be an extension of the FeatureParser itself rather than independent?

Comment: a lot depends on how you make the shared calls. unable to say given this information

Comment: added image showing the result of json pretty print

Comment: I meant the calls not the JSON

Comment: sorry pretty print image and comment was for a different post.  I updated the above and moved it to the correct post

Comment: After a ton of rework and lack of feedback, we solved this by moving authentication to an authentication.feature file call in the background of the feature file rather than calling this from the config file.  The call to the authentication.feature file within the config appears to make the auth call only once, and hold that variable at a shared scope level rather than an isolated scope for the feature file itself which is not desired when we have different feature files using different authentication headers for different users.